# How to solve the 'Unable to find Asm for stackmap generation' error on startup of STS?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, installation, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to use the **Spring Tool Suite 3.8.3** on Ubuntu 16.04. Upon startup I get this error:

> An internal error occured during: "Initializing Java Tooling"

with the detailed message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling". Unable
>   to find Asm for stackmap generation (Looking for
>   'aj.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader'). Stackmap generation for woven
>   code is required to avoid verify errors on a Java 1.7 or higher
>   runtime when weaving type org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchPattern
>   when weaving classes  when weaving

I have to admit that I have no idea what I should do here and I failed to find any pointers online. Any advice or hint is welcome.

Comment: I would recommend to file an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues and attach the full stack trace to that issue. You can find the details and hopefully the full stack trace in the Error Log view in Eclipse/STS.

Comment: I tried all the answers and none worked. I ended up installing a fresh version of eclipse and it solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have installed Java 9 on your system. That's why you are facing compatibility issue and getting the stated errors. I therefore suggest you to degrade your java version to 8 for which it will work well and you wont be facing any error issue in that.
You can install java8 from this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04)!

Comment: This option doesn't seem to work with the new Eclipse-2020-09 upgrade. :(

Comment: same here, updated to new eclipse and JDK11 is required.

Comment: Faced the same issue in eclipse 2020-12 (4.18.0) version after installing scala plugin.
After removal of scala plugin everthing back to normal.

Answer (score 9):

It was for me due to the **scala plug-in** which I have installed a few days back. **Uninstall the scala plugin** and change to JDK 8 or JDK 11 it will work.

Comment: Same for me, removed scala plugin and it's fixed.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad, it was helpful.

Comment: I just had the same problem, and in my case it was the Kotlin language support plugin that needed to be uninstalled. This, to me, suggests it might have something to do with mostly any compiled language that gets added to Eclipse - both Scala and Kotlin get compiled, but are not plain Java.

Comment: @user625488 I think you are right. But in my case I need Kotlin language support. I can't uninstall it. Any ideas how to get it to work with such plugins? Thank you.

Comment: I dig a little mode it's due to aspectj which not found org.objectweb.asm by  https://github.com/eclipse/org.aspectj/blob/master/weaver/src/main/java/org/aspectj/weaver/bcel/asm/AsmDetector.java. But I found it in my eclipse plugin directory. I add the optional dependancy on manifest but it still not working

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still having a similar problem with Eclipse and needs to use Java 11 or higher (Eclipse nowadays seems to require Java 11) then have a look into this plugin as it seems to be required for the kotlin plugin.
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/aspectj-development-tools

Comment: oh come on... how did you find that?! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had to downgrade the JRE used to run Eclipse. Downgrading from Java 15 to Java 11 solved the problem.

Use the `-vm` option in `eclipse.ini`, eg.

```
 -vm
 c:\Dev\jdk-11\bin
```

Answer (score 0):

My STS did not even start after installing scala plugin. I had to manually delete scala jars and folders from the STS /plugins. After that it started working.