# Eclipse unable to find Asm

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

My eclipse just updated to 2020-09 (4.17.0). After manually setting the JVM in the ini from my OracleJDK8 to OpenJDK11 (using [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996047/eclipse-incompatible-jvm-version-1-8-0-261-of-the-jvm-is-not-suitable-for-thi)), I was able to start it again. However, on startup I get the following error message:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
Unable to find Asm for stackmap generation (Looking for 'aj.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader'). Stackmap generation for woven code is required to avoid verify errors on a Java 1.7 or higher runtime
when weaving type org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.SearchDocument
when weaving classes 
when weaving
```

When trying to save a file I get a similar error:

```
Save Failed
Unable to find Asm for stackmap generation (Looking for 'aj.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader'). Stackmap generation for woven code is required to avoid verify errors on a Java 1.7 or higher runtime
when weaving type org.eclipse.jdt.ui.cleanup.CleanUpContext
when weaving classes 
when weaving 
when weaving type org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.QuickFixProcessor
when weaving classes 
when weaving
```

Changing the ini to use OpenJDK15 (and setting the two `requiredJavaVersion` flags accordingly) fixed the tooling error, but I'm still unable to save files. The error message is similar, although the "stack trace" is significantly longer (so long that the error message doesn't fit onto my screen).

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43141563/how-to-solve-the-unable-to-find-asm-for-stackmap-generation-error-on-startup-o) discusses a similar problem with a different IDE and suggests downgrading to Java 1.8 which in my case is no longer possible because Eclipse requires at least Java11 now.

Any ideas except downgrading Eclipse again?

---

**EDIT**: As it turns out, doing a fresh install with the eclipse installer from their website *including their JDK* does the job. However, if anybody has an idea what's the problem with using OpenJDK, let me know...

Comment: Obviously you have skipped some versions. Do you have [Eclipse Object Teams](https://www.eclipse.org/objectteams) installed? If yes, which version? Are there any other plug-ins you have installed?

Comment: Thanks! I got mine zip installed version working by just updating my JDK. Went from OpenJDK 11.0.4.11 to 11.0.8.10.

Comment: Nope, got another one trying to launch a junit configuration:

`An internal error occurred during: "Launching acc-test".`
`Unable to find Asm for stackmap generation (Looking for 'aj.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader').`
`Stackmap generation for woven code is required to avoid verify errors on a Java 1.7 or higher runtime`
`when weaving type org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.search.matching.PossibleMatch`
`when weaving classes`
`when weaving`

Comment: I continued to get similar errors for other parts so I ended up using the installer to get the "bundled" jdk. That worked great for a few days and then I was back to getting ASM and weaving errors for various things including searches. I tried installing the "Eclipse Automated Error Reporting" feature to reporting these hard to reproduce errors but then I could no longer open JDK classes like DateTimeFormmatter; even after reverting the error reporting install. For now, my only recourse seems to be going back my 2020-06 install and workspace. :(

Comment: restarting eclipse fixed these errors for me

Comment: Getting the same thing after installing ScalaIDE on Eclipse. The fresh install was working  fine before that...